# What does a slash mean in a full-load current value?

Tags: current, dc-motor

The full load current of a motor is **less than or equal to 35.6/26.7A**[image]

What does this mean?
Also , the max current of the controller (made for this motor) is 30A.
How can it be that the max current is lower than his motor.

Comment: Please provide context such as a link to the datasheet.

Comment: This may be a spec of typical starting current versus running current. Often the starting current could be larger unless the torque load on the motor is limited.

Comment: http://www.benl.ebay.be/itm/MY1020-1000W-36V-48V-DC-Motor-3-2-Nm-brush-motor-Forandor-/131816750879?var=&hash=item1eb0e3ff1f:m:m7J45SN2G8VShcDa_0qUKxA

Comment: Thanks for the link. We encourage that you add the additional information to your question rather than sprinkle it through the comments. That way all the information required to answer your question is in the one place.

Answer (score 5):

You can see in that datasheet this table:
[image]

Those currents (full load currents) are related to input voltage (rated voltage).

35.6A is for 48V

26.7A is for 60V

**UPDATE:**

Title of that item is "MY1020 1000W 36V|48V DC-Motor 3.2 Nm", but there is no such motor in description. So, whether title or table is wrong. You should ask seller to clarify that.

Comment: It would appear to be a 36V/48V motor with some careless editing in the table, by comparison with the current for 500W/24V motor (26.7A) or the 500W 36V motor (17.8A). As a cross check, 25A/50V would be 1250W in, for 80% efficiency. Work out the actual efficiency if you're interested. It also means at 36V you'll need a bigger controller if you want full power.